# execute multiple commands with angular cli

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli

I have created an Angular app. I have created mock server using json-server plugin from node.

Currently problem with this is, I have to open multiple command prompt to run json server and angular cli.

Is there any way where I can execute both the commands in parallel. OR
is there any way where I will run ng serve and in behind it runs the json-server command as well?

Comment: You could add a script to your package file that uses e.g. [concurrently](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently) to run both commands (see e.g. https://github.com/textbook/salary-stats/blob/046cfb059dd1b7e141141ef018a8ee029232221c/package.json#L24). But this is really nothing to do with Angular generally or the CLI specifically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try to use the package called concurrently.

npm install concurrently --save-dev

Then setup your package.json scripts:

```
"start": "concurrently --kill-others \"npm run server\" \"ng serve\""
```

or on unix systems without the library

```
"start": "npm run server | ng serve"
```